# Auto-versioning in ASP.NET MVC for CSS / JS Files?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, url-routing

I have read lots of article on how to auto-version your CSS/JS files - but none of these really provide an elegant way to do this in ASP.NET MVC.

This link - [How to force browser to reload cached CSS/JS files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118884/what-is-an-elegant-way-to-force-browsers-to-reload-cached-css-js-files) - provides a solution for Apache - but I'm a little confused how this could be implemented via ASP.NET MVC ?

Would anyone be able to provide some advice how to do this on IIS7 and ASP.NET MVC - so that CSS/JS files automatically have a version number inserted in the URL without changing the location of the file ?

That is, so links come out link this etc presumably using the URL Rewrite or ?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/structure.1194900443.css" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.1197993206.js"></script>
```

Thx

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When faced with this problem I wrote a series of wrapper functions around the `UrlHelper`'s `Content` method:

EDIT:

Following the discussions in the comments below I updated this code:

```
public static class UrlHelperExtensions
{
    private readonly static string _version = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();

    private static string GetAssetsRoot()
    {
        string root = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AssetsRoot"];
        return root.IsNullOrEmpty() ? "~" : root;
    }

    public static string Image(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content(string.Format("{0}/v{2}/assets/img/{1}", GetAssetsRoot(), fileName, _version));
    }

    public static string Asset(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content(string.Format("{0}/v{2}/assets/{1}", GetAssetsRoot(), fileName, _version));
    }

    public static string Stylesheet(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content(string.Format("{0}/v{2}/assets/css/{1}", GetAssetsRoot(), fileName, _version));
    }

    public static string Script(this UrlHelper helper, string fileName)
    {
        return helper.Content(string.Format("{0}/v{2}/assets/js/{1}", GetAssetsRoot(), fileName, _version));
    }
}
```

Using these functions in conjunction with the following `rewrite` rule should work:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Rewrite assets">
      <match url="^v(.*?)/assets/(.*?)" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/assets/{R:2}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

[This article](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/) discusses how to create rewrite rules on IIS7.

This code uses the version number of the current assembly as a query string parameter on the file path's it emits.  When I do an update to the site and the build number increments, so does the querystring parameter on the file, and so the user agent will re-download the file.

Comment: hey clonked - thanks a lot for code however the problem with using the version number is detailed in the article linked above. It will prevent caching, because requests with GET parameters may not be cached (per the HTTP spec) and IE is notorious with ignoring the version number - so thats why I wanted a way to include the version number within the URL /file.123.css - ala URL Rewrite

Comment: My apologies, I did not read the content of your link.  I'm glad though that I participated though, as I have learned my methods were incorrect!  I will see if I can revise my solution and share it.

Comment: I have updated the code I posted to use IIS 7's URL rewriting functionality.

Comment: oh cool great thanks :) so you are using the rewrite kit via http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/04/20/tip-trick-fix-common-seo-problems-using-the-url-rewrite-extension.aspx ?

Comment: Yes the rewrite rule I posted should work with the IIS7 Rewrite module from Microsoft.

Comment: This it didn't quite work for me until I changed the match to "<match url="^v(.*?)/Content/(.*)$" />" - which took me ages to find out! Perhaps this comment will save someone else some time. Other then that it was perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** The previous version did not work on Azure, I have simplified and corrected below.  (Note, for this to work in development mode with IIS Express, you will need to install URL Rewrite 2.0 from Microsoft http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite - it uses the WebPi installer, make sure to close Visual Studio first)

**UPDATE:** Fixed rule for .min files

I recently spent an entirely fruitless day trying to get automatic bundling (to support auto-versioning) in C# / Net 4.6 / MVC 5 / Razor to work.  I read many articles both on StackOverflow and elsewhere, yet I could not find an end-to-end walk through of how to set it up.  I also do not care for the way files are version-ed (by appending a query string with version to the static file request - ie. somefile.js?v=1234) because I have been told by some that certain proxy servers ignore query strings when caching static resources.

So after a short trip down the rabbit hole, I've rolled my own version for auto-versioning and included full instructions on how to get it working below.

Full discussion @: [Simplified Auto-Versioning of Javascript / CSS in ASP.NET MVC 5 to stop caching issues (works in Azure and Locally) With or Without URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150401/simplified-auto-versioning-of-javascript-css-in-asp-net-mvc-5-to-stop-caching)

***THE PROBLEM:*** You generally have 2 types of javascript / css files in a project.

1) 3 party libraries (such as jquery or mustache) that very rarely change (and when they do, the version on the file generally changes) - these can be bundled / minified on an "as-needed" basis using WebGrease or JSCompress.com (just include the bundled file/version in your _Layout.cshtml)

2) page specific css/js files that should be refreshed whenever a new build is pushed. (without having the user clear thier cache or do multiple refreshes)

***My Solution:***  Auto-increment the assembly version every time the project is built, and use that number for a routed static file on the specific resources you would like to keep refreshed. (so something.js is included as something.v1234.js with 1234 automatically changing every time the project is built) - I also added some additional functionality to ensure that .min.js files are used in production and regular.js files are used when debugging (I am using WebGrease to automate the minify process) One nice thing about this solution is that it works in local / dev mode as well as production.

***How to do it:***  Auto-increment the assembly version every time the project is built, and use that number for a routed static file on the specific resources you would like to keep refreshed. (so something.js is included as something.v1234.js with 1234 automatically changing every time the project is built) - I also added some additional functionality to ensure that .min.js files are used in production and regular.js files are used when debugging (I am using WebGrease to automate the minify process) One nice thing about this solution is that it works in local / dev mode as well as production. (I am using Visual Studio 2015 / Net 4.6, but I believe this will work in earlier versions as well.

**Step 1:** Enable auto-increment on the assembly when built
In the AssemblyInfo.cs file (found under the "properties" section of your project change the following lines:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

to

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0.*")]
//[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
```

**Step 2:** Set up url rewrite in web.config for files with embedded version slugs (see step 3)

In web.config (the main one for the project) add the follwing rules in the  system.webServer.

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="static-autoversion">
      <match url="^(.*)([.]v[0-9]+)([.](js|css))$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:3}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="static-autoversion-min">
      <match url="^(.*)([.]v[0-9]+)([.]min[.](js|css))$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}{R:3}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

**Step 3:** Setup Application Variables to read your current assembly version and create version slugs in your js and css files.

in Global.asax.cs (found in the root of the project) add the following code to protected void Application_Start()  (after the Register lines)

```
            // setup application variables to write versions in razor (including .min extension when not debugging)
            string addMin = ".min";
            if (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) { addMin = ""; }  // don't use minified files when executing locally
            Application["JSVer"] = "v" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Replace('.','0') + addMin + ".js";
            Application["CSSVer"] = "v" + System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString().Replace('.', '0') + addMin + ".css";
```

**Step 4:** Change src links in Razor views using the application variables we set up in Global.asax.cs

```
@HttpContext.Current.Application["CSSVer"]
@HttpContext.Current.Application["JSVer"]
```

For example, in my _Layout.cshtml, in my head section, I have the following block of code for stylesheets:

```
<!-- Load all stylesheets -->
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://fontastic.s3.amazonaws.com/8NNKTYdfdJLQS3D4kHqhLT/icons.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/Content/css/main-small.@HttpContext.Current.Application["CSSVer"]' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='(min-width: 700px)' href='/Content/css/medium.@HttpContext.Current.Application["CSSVer"]' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='(min-width: 700px)' href='/Content/css/large.@HttpContext.Current.Application["CSSVer"]' />
@RenderSection("PageCSS", required: false)
```

A couple things to notice here: 1) there is **no extension** on the file.  2) there is no .min either.  Both of these are handled by the code in Global.asax.cs

Likewise, (also in _Layout.cs) in my javascript section:  I have the following code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/all3bnd100.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/ui.@HttpContext.Current.Application["JSVer"]" type="text/javascript"></script>
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

The first file is a bundle of all my 3rd party libraries I've created manually with WebGrease.  If I add or change any of the files in the bundle (which is rare) then I manually rename the file to all3bnd101.min.js, all3bnd102.min.js, etc...  This file does not match the rewrite handler, so will remain cached on the client browser until you manually re-bundle / change the name.

The second file is ui.js (which will be written as ui.v12345123.js or ui.v12345123.min.js depending on if you are running in debug mode or not) This will be handled / rewritten.  (you can set a breakpoint in Application_OnBeginRequest of Global.asax.cs to watch it work)

Full discussion on this at: [Simplified Auto-Versioning of Javascript / CSS in ASP.NET MVC 5 to stop caching issues (works in Azure and Locally) With or Without URL Rewrite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34150401/simplified-auto-versioning-of-javascript-css-in-asp-net-mvc-5-to-stop-caching) ***(Including a way to do it WITHOUT URL Rewrite)***

Answer (score -1):

I usually append a fake query string to my resource files.. i.e

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/structure.css?v=1194900443" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/prototype.js?v=1197993206"></script>
```

It doesn't require any url helpers and works no matter what's running the in background. To be honest I haven't throughly tested this method, but I've found it always fixes any resource caching issues people were experiencing.

You'd probably have to update the `v=` manually, but it wouldn't be terribly hard to append a version parameter to the resources from a config file somewhere.

**Edit:**

I went back and throughly read through the content of the link above and realize you've probably already discarded this method. Apologies for suggesting it again.

Comment: This prevented caching altogether when I tested it in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I've done the same, and for the querystring value it is determined by opening the file with a `File.OpenRead()` call and then doing an `MD55.Create().ComputeHash(stream)` for it, and that is put into the querystring, which changes it each time the file is updated. This value is stored in app cache after initial retrieval. Works great for the limited usage of it in the things I've worked on.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose next solution with advanced options (debug/release mode, versions):

Js or Css files included by such way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/exampleScript<%=Global.JsPostfix%>" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Css/exampleCss<%=Global.CssPostfix%>" />
```

Global.JsPostfix and Global.CssPostfix is calculated by the following way in Global.asax:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    string jsVersion = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["JsVersion"];
    bool updateEveryAppStart = Convert.ToBoolean(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UpdateJsEveryAppStart"]);
    int buildNumber = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.Revision;
    JsPostfix = "";
#if !DEBUG
    JsPostfix += ".min";
#endif      
    JsPostfix += ".js?" + jsVersion + "_" + buildNumber;
    if (updateEveryAppStart)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        JsPosfix += "_" + rand.Next();
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don!t think you can add <%=Global.JsPostfix%> kind of server code in head tag with runat="server" property.