# Is there a way to automatically append datetime to js and css using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I am currently adding `?t=@(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"))` to every single js or css file in my project to update the cache automatically. Is there a way to make a c# method that will do that for me everytime i use a new js and/or css ?

Comment: are you using core?   https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/aspappendversion-feature-in-asp-net-core

Comment: @BryanDellinger That looks like exactly what i need. Sadly, i am not using Core... is there a similar solution for non core users ?

Comment: the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818799/autoversioning-css-js-in-asp-net-mvc) provides a decent way to implement this.  BTW, what you are doing is called versioning, that may help you in searching