# ASP.NET MVC: how to append a token to CSS URL properly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I can append a token to my script references like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Some.js?<%= Html.GetToken() %>"></script>
```

... and this works fine. But, if I try to append the same token the same way to a CSS file reference:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Some.css?<%= Html.GetToken() %>" />
```

... the IIS generates the following markup:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/Some.css?&lt;%= Html.GetToken() %>" />
```

I know I'm missing something super simple but I cannot see what exactly. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Does your `<head>` section have `runat="server"` as `orip` suggested?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens if your `<head>` section has `runat="server"`. If you can live without it (in ASP.NET MVC you usually can) try it this way.

If not, add or modify the CSS link in your view's `Page_Load`. If that sounds awful to you, then removing `runat="server"` should be working :)

Comment: Thanks! That was it - runat in the head. Very strange, though. Looks like a bug in MS code, isn't it?

Comment: Dunno, in my experience WebForms templating has many unexpected behaviors in order to enable their complex features.

Comment: runat="server" tells asp.net that the tag is to be a server-side control. At that point you can no longer treat it like a literal and insert your inline values.

Comment: @shiznit123 - yeah, but why does it work with a `<script>` subelement but not with a `<link>` subelement? Just another `HtmlHead` quirk.

Answer (score 0):

There a trick you can use for auto versioning.

Check out the post here:

[Auto-versioning in ASP.NET MVC for CSS / JS Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841455/auto-versioning-in-asp-net-mvc-for-css-js-files)